# disable escaping/urlencoding in Twig_SimpleFunction

Tags: php, twig, silex

i know it's one of the common and frequently asked questions about twig, but i get stuck and confused

**Problem:** Function output will be escaped and instead of `/?some_var=value&maybe_another_var=another_value` I get `%2F%3Fsome_var%3Dvalue%26maybe_another_var%3Danother_value` which completelly ruins my anchor-tags

**Goal**: I'm trying to **prevent** auto_urlencoding which happens all the time with my custom function.

**What I use:** a [utilphp::util::add_query_arg()](http://brandonwamboldt.github.io/utilphp/#add_query_arg) method and a custom Twig-Function (`Twig_SimpleFunction`)

**How I use it:** in the **code**

```
$twig->addFunction( new \Twig_SimpleFunction('util_add_query_args', 
            function(){
                    return \utilphp\util::add_query_arg( func_get_args() ); 
            },
            array('is_safe' => array('all')) //also tried array('html') but didn't worked
    ));
```

**How I use it:** in the **tempalte**

```
<img src="//{{app_host_name}}/{{ other_url_segments}}{{ util_add_query_args( {'fontStyle' : style } , data.query_string )}}">
```

this should ***append*** `&fontStyle=value_from_variable` to the given query string and return it **as is**

`data.query_string` — may already contain a querysting like `?some_var=value&maybe_another_var=another_value` but it can be different from one request to another. In some cases it's empty, so in order to get a *valid* query sting i have to use `util::add_query_arg()` since it also covers such cases

**Didn't work:**

- adding `|raw` to `{{ util_add_query_args( {'fontStyle' : style } , data.query_string ) }}`
- adding 
  `{% autoescape false %} 
  <img src="//{{app_host_name}}/{{ other_url_segments}}{{ util_add_query_args( {'fontStyle' : style } , data.query_string )}}"> 
  {% endautoescape %}`

What do I missing?! How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, it seems like `func_get_args()` was "the bad guy". Do not know why exactly, but since I changed

```
function(){
   return \utilphp\util::add_query_arg( func_get_args() ); 
}
```

to

```
function($args_arr, $query_string){
    return \utilphp\util::add_query_arg( $args_arr, $query_string ); 
}
```

it works... and no `{% autoescape false %}` or `|raw` needed too.